# android - Progress Bar freezes while loading data using Volley

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-volley

I am using Progress Bar that only shows up at the time of loading data using Volley but my progress bar freezes till the data loads. Please help. Below is the code that is working fine except the progress bar freezes.

```
 private class GetValue extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    ProgressDialog progressDialog=null;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "Loading Data...", "Please Wait");

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        super.onPostExecute(result);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        assignValues(mnyr ,mnyr1);          
        return null;
    }
}

  private void assignValues(String s1, String s2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //C.progressStart(context, "Loading Data...", "Please Wait");
    final String s = s1;
    final List<List<String>> values = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
    datas = new ArrayList<CustomData>();
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    String val = s1 + "/" + s2;
    final StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Method.GET, C.EVENTS + val,
            new Listener<String>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    JsonParser parent = new JsonParser(arg0);
                    if(parent.getValue("data") == null){
                    int length = parent.getArrLength(arg0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog=null; // inside asynTask method

 @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(uractivity.this, "Wait", "Downloading...");

    }

 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        super.onPostExecute(result);
progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
```